# I have 2 versions of python installed, but cmake is using older version. How do I force cmake to use the newer version?

Tags: python, python-2.7, cmake

I have 2 versions of python installed, but **cmake** is using older version. How do I force **cmake** to use the newer version?

Answer (score 55):

You may try either of these depending on what you need:

### For `CMake >= 3.12`

According to the changelog:

> New "FindPython3" and "FindPython2" modules, as well as a new
>   "FindPython" module, have been added to provide a new way to locate
>   python environments.

```
find_package(Python COMPONENTS Interpreter Development)
```

**[Docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPython.html#module:FindPython):**

> This module looks preferably for version 3 of Python. If not found,
>   version 2 is searched. To manage concurrent versions 3 and 2 of
>   Python, use FindPython3 and FindPython2 modules rather than this one.

### For `CMake < 3.12`

**[Docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/module/FindPythonInterp.html):**

```
find_package(PythonInterp 2.7 REQUIRED)
find_package(PythonLibs 2.7 REQUIRED)
```

Comment: Works nicely, also using Travis.

Comment: So easy... I feel dumb.

Comment: Works also for python 3.6 installed with Conda in user home directory!

Comment: Wait i dont get this, how do you use this? like what is the command i can use in my command line?

Comment: @Tarun it goes into CMakeLists.txt and cmake is the command, here is a [more complete example](https://github.com/dev-cafe/cmake-cookbook/blob/f8175d47f1b178368f67e04049375fd494831047/chapter-03/recipe-01/example/CMakeLists.txt)

Comment: cold somebody provide the command for "just find me any python2 version"? Are those parameters: `Python COMPONENTS Interpreter Development`

Comment: Same here, I do not get what to do with or where to put this thing:
find_package(Python COMPONENTS Interpreter Development) and if I should put it as it is or should replace COMPONENTS Interpreter Development for something else

Comment: As I understand `COMPONENTS` is a keyword / name of the option and `Interpreter Development` are the values. Other components like `Compiler` and `NumPy` are also supported. See [find_package docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#command:find_package)

Comment: How do you specify python 3.4 or 3.6 or 3.73 ? I want to explicitly specify python.

Answer (score 44):

Try to add `-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=/path/to/python2.7`
It might be a path problem?

Also could specify the path to your python library,use your version that you want:

```
 cmake -DPYTHON_LIBRARIES=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/libpython2.7.dylib .
```

Comment: Note that at least for cmake 2.8 on Ubuntu 16.04, you need to set -DPYTHON_LIBRARY instead of -DPYTHON_LIBRARIES

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Python_EXECUTABLE`? [ref](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPython.html)

Answer (score 36):

I had a similar problem, and resolved it using [Paul's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15291663/712526) as a hint. I needed to use `python2.7` to compile an older library, but `cmake` keeps picking up my `python3.2` libraries (and executable).

First, I ran `cmake` with default options, then edited the `CMakeCache.txt` file which it generated. I did it this way primarily because I didn't know the proper `-D...` incantations to cause `cmake` to get the python library and include paths, etc right in the first place.

In my `CmakeCache.txt`, I found lines like this

- Path to a program

  ```
  PYTHON_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/python
  ```
- Path to a directory

  ```
  PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=/usr/include/python3.2
  ```
- Path to a library

  ```
  PYTHON_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/libpython3.2.so
  ```

And replaced every occurrence of `python3.2` with `python2.7`. I also had to rename the `PYTHON_EXECUTABLE` to use `python2.7`, since `python` is a symlink to `python3.2` on my system.

Then I reran `cmake`. Because it prefers its cached values to actually looking for the libraries, this should work in all cases. At least, it did in mine.

Comment: This is what worked for me.  Providing cmake environment variables did not work.  Editing the CmakeCache file did.  It's easier to work with anyways

Answer (score 12):

I use anaconda(python 2.7.8) as well as python 2.7.6.

I tried `-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=$ANACONDA_HOME/bin`, but version 1.4 found (weird:).

My solution is changing it to PYTHON_EXECUTABLE:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -DBUILD_TIFF=ON \
-DPYTHON_LIBRARY=$ANACONDA_HOME/lib/libpython2.7.so \
-DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=$ANACONDA_HOME/include/python2.7/ \
-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=$ANACONDA_HOME/bin/python
```

Comment: For anaconda in particular, this worked for me (and will hopefully generalize more easily): https://github.com/jkhoogland/FindPythonAnaconda (though I had to make two small changes -- they're both in my GitHub fork if upstream doesn't quite work for you either)

Answer (score 1):

My use case was a rather large project in which C++ classes were made available to Python scripts via `Boost.Python`. After having fought the various quirks of CMake's Python interpreter and library detection, I finally gave up and rolled my own. My approach is based on a slightly after-edited version of the `python-config` script that is *sometimes* (but not always!) put into a newly created virtual environment ([see this SO post on `pyvenv`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42020937/why-pyvenv-does-not-install-python-config/48946977#48946977) for these issues, but I digress). This script is invoked by a small CMake snippet `pyconfig.cmake`. Both are freely available from the GitHub repo [cmake-python-config](https://github.com/aaszodi/cmake-python-config).

Warning: The scripts assume that you have a Python 3 interpreter in your `PATH`. Detection of Python 2 is not attempted. The scripts do *not* attempt to find *all* installed versions of Python3  either.

Answer (score 1):

on my windows platform like below, unix should be similar:

```
-DPython3_EXECUTABLE="C:\Users\xx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe" `
-DPython3_LIBRARY="C:\Users\xx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\libs\python310.lib" `
-DPython3_INCLUDE_DIR="C:\Users\xx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include" `
```