# Cmake is not able to find Python-libraries

Tags: python, python-2.7, cmake

Getting this error:

```
sudo: unable to resolve host coderw@ll
-- Could NOT find PythonLibs (missing:  PYTHON_LIBRARIES PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS) 
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:108     
(message):
Could NOT find PythonInterp (missing: PYTHON_EXECUTABLE)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
/usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:315  
(_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
/usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPythonInterp.cmake:139 
(FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
Code/cmake/Modules/FindNumPy.cmake:10 (find_package)
CMakeLists.txt:114 (find_package)



-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/coderwall/Desktop/rdkit/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/coderwall/Desktop/rdkit/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

I have already installed:

1. sudo apt-get install python-dev
2. Environment variable are already set as follow:

   ```
   PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS=/usr/include/python2.7 
   PYTHON_LIBRARIES=/usr/lib/python2.7/config/libpython2.7.so
   ```

Location of `python.h` : `/usr/lib/include/python2.7/python.h`

Location of `python` libs: `/usr/lib/python2.7/`
How to solve this?

Comment: Hmmm, try setting `PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=...`?

Comment: Tried and it recognized but still : `Could NOT find PythonLibs (missing:  PYTHON_LIBRARIES PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS) `

Comment: Could you please include the code of the rdkit root CMakeLists.txt file to your question? That might help.

Answer (score 79):

You can fix the errors by appending to the `cmake` command the `-DPYTHON_LIBRARY` and `-DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR` flags filled with the respective folders.

Thus, the trick is to fill those parameters with the returned information from the python interpreter, which is the most reliable. This may work independently of your python location/version (also for Anaconda users):

```
$ cmake .. \
-DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=$(python -c "import sysconfig; print(sysconfig.get_path('include'))")  \
-DPYTHON_LIBRARY=$(python -c "import sysconfig; print(sysconfig.get_config_var('LIBDIR'))")
```

If the version of python that you want to link against cmake is Python3.X and the default python symlink points to Python2.X, `python3 -c ...` can be used instead of `python -c ...`.

In case that the error persists, you may need to update the `cmake` to a higher version as stated by @pdpcosta and repeat the process again.

Comment: print(sysconfig.get_config_var('LIBDIR'))"  

prints /opt/conda/lib, but then I get 

WARNING: Target "something-something" requests linking to directory "/opt/conda/lib".  Targets may link only to libraries.  CMake is dropping the item.

 - Do we need to give -DPYTHON_LIBRARY the path to the .so libpython?

Comment: @Mr.WorshipMe yes, I changed the command to give the path to the .so like so:

`-DPYTHON_LIBRARY=$(python -c "import distutils.sysconfig as sysconfig; import os; print(os.path.join(sysconfig.get_config_var('LIBDIR'), sysconfig.get_config_var('LDLIBRARY')))")`

Comment: For anaconda in particular, this worked for me (and will hopefully generalize more easily): https://github.com/jkhoogland/FindPythonAnaconda (though I had to make two small changes -- they're both in my GitHub fork if upstream doesn't quite work for you either)

Comment: This is the best answer, as it automatically adjusts to the current python (`which python`) and works seamlessly when a conda env is active).

Comment: Note (I hope it helps M1 Mac people using Cmake with Python 3): in my case in order to make my specific problem work I needed to do `DPYTHON3_LIBRARY` and `DPYTHON3_INCLUDE_DIR`. It didn't work without the 3.

Comment: For anybody else seeing the deprecation warning for `distutils.sysconfig`.

You can use `sysconfig` and call `sysconfig.get_path('include')` for the -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR and `sysconfig.get_config_var('LIBDIR')`

Answer (score 47):

For me this is helpful:

```
# if using python2
apt-get install python-dev

# if using python3
apt-get install python3-dev
```

Comment: For me (on Centos7) this line solved the issue:
`yum install python34-devel`

Comment: This worked for me, without any of the cmake arguments (`-DPYTHON_LIBRARY` etc) suggested by the other answers. I had `python-dev`, but had forgotten `python3-dev`.

Comment: Very bad answer. It's like, if it doesn't work, try to install everything. It's either python2 or python3 you need... (Now in 2020, better update your answer as python2 is deprecated)

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer.

Comment: This solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 21):

I hit the same issue,and discovered the error message gives misleading variable names. Try setting the following (singular instead of plural):

```
PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/python2.7 
PYTHON_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/python2.7/config/libpython2.7.so
```

The (plural) variables you see error messages about are values that the PythonLibs sets up when it is initialised correctly.

Comment: This really needs to be mentioned in the documentation for opencv installs. Also they could be a little more helpful about explaining the available cmake options when building from source. http://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html

Answer (score 19):

Even after adding `-DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR` and `-DPYTHON_LIBRARY` as suggested above, I was still facing the error `Could NOT find PythonInterp`. What solved it was adding `-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=` to `cmake` as suggested in https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/issues/99#issuecomment-182071479:

```
cmake .. \
-DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=$(python -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_inc; print(get_python_inc())")  \
-DPYTHON_LIBRARY=$(python -c "import distutils.sysconfig as sysconfig; print(sysconfig.get_config_var('LIBDIR'))") \
-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=`which python`
```

Comment: Thanks! I also found that github page but I was only setting the PYTHON_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH and that didn't work. Your solution solved my issue when trying to build OpenVDB on MacOSX (Mojave).

Comment: Thanks so much, I can't find libpython-x.so and failed to manual compile&install opencv-python, and this way solved my prolem

Answer (score 15):

I was facing this problem while trying to compile OpenCV 3 on a Xubuntu 14.04 Thrusty Tahr system.
With all the dev packages of Python installed, the configuration process was always returning the message:

```
Could NOT found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python2.7 (found suitable version "2.7.6", minimum required is "2.7")
Could NOT find PythonLibs (missing: PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS) (found suitable exact version "2.7.6")
Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python3.4 (found suitable version "3.4", minimum required is "3.4")
Could NOT find PythonLibs (missing: PYTHON_LIBRARIES) (Required is exact version "3.4.0")
```

The CMake version available on Thrusty Tahr repositories is 2.8.
Some posts inspired me to upgrade CMake.
I've added a PPA CMake repository which installs CMake version 3.2.

After the upgrade everything ran smoothly and the compilation was successful.

Comment: And do not forget clean all cmake caches firstly!

Comment: @acgtyrant   how do you do that? cmake clean?

Answer (score 10):

Some last version of Ubuntu installs Python 3.4 by default and the CMake version from Ubuntu (2.8) only searches up to Python 3.3.

Try to add `set(Python_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS 3.4)` before the `find_package` statement.

Remember to clean `CMakeCache.txt` too.

Comment: This was the problem for my 14.04 Ubuntu system. I fixed it by installing a newer cmake version (https://askubuntu.com/a/945589/187411)

Comment: I solved the problem by `Remember to clean CMakeCache.txt too.` many thanks Patrizio. in the mbec-cli2 CMake (not found jinja2, intelhex, prettytable).

Answer (score 7):

This problem can also happen in Windows. Cmake looks into the registry and sometimes python values are not set. For those with similar problem:

http://ericsilva.org/2012/10/11/restoring-your-python-registry-in-windows/

Just create a .reg file to set the necessary keys and edit accordingly to match your setup.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Python]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Python\Pythoncore]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Python\Pythoncore\2.6]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Python\Pythoncore\2.6\InstallPath]
@="C:\\python26"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Python\Pythoncore\2.6\PythonPath]
@="C:\\python26;C:\\python26\\Lib\\;C:\\python26\\DLLs\\"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Python\Pythoncore\2.7]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Python\Pythoncore\2.7\InstallPath]
@="C:\\python27"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Python\Pythoncore\2.7\PythonPath]
@="C:\\python27;C:\\python27\\Lib\\;C:\\python27\\DLLs\\"
```

Comment: Will this also work if I have both 32 and 64 bit versions installed at the same time and want to build both 32 and 64 bit C++ binaries?

Answer (score 2):

Note that if you are using cMake version 3.12 or later, variable `PythonInterp` and `PythonLibs` has been changed into `Python`.

So we use:

`find_package(Python ${PY_VERSION} REQUIRED)`

instead of:

`find_package(PythonInterp ${PY_VERSION} REQUIRED)`
`find_package(PythonLibs ${PY_VERSION} REQUIRED)`

see https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/module/FindPython.html for details.

Answer (score 2):

I had upgraded to python3.8 on my system and had an incomplete install. Managed to fix it by installing the rest of the 3.8 packages:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.8 python3.8-dev python3.8-distutils python3.8-venv
```

Answer (score 1):

Paste this into your CMakeLists.txt:

```
# find python
execute_process(COMMAND python-config --prefix OUTPUT_VARIABLE PYTHON_SEARCH_PATH)
string(REGEX REPLACE "\n$" "" PYTHON_SEARCH_PATH "${PYTHON_SEARCH_PATH}")
file(GLOB_RECURSE PYTHON_DY_LIBS ${PYTHON_SEARCH_PATH}/lib/libpython*.dylib ${PYTHON_SEARCH_PATH}/lib/libpython*.so)
if (PYTHON_DY_LIBS)
    list(GET PYTHON_DY_LIBS 0 PYTHON_LIBRARY)
    message("-- Find shared libpython: ${PYTHON_LIBRARY}")
else()
    message(WARNING "Cannot find shared libpython, try find_package")
endif()

find_package(PythonInterp)
find_package(PythonLibs ${PYTHON_VERSION_STRING} EXACT)
```

Answer (score 1):

In case that might help, I found a workaround for a similar problem, looking at the cmake doc :
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindPythonLibs.html

You must set two env vars for cmake to find coherent versions.
Unfortunately this is not a generic solution...

```
cmake -DPYTHON_LIBRARY=${HOME}/.pyenv/versions/3.8.0/lib/libpython3.8.a -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=${HOME}/.pyenv/versions/3.8.0/include/python3.8/ cern_root/
```

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 20 at least, since Python 2.7 is deprecated, you can:

```sh
sudo apt install python2.7-dev
```

And then `PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR` can be set to `/usr/include/python2.7`

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3.2 and onward `distutils.sysconfig` is deprecated in favor of `sysconfig`.

To get all the variable names in data structure and inspect the situation we can use [get_paths](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sysconfig.html#sysconfig.get_paths) function

```py
import sysconfig
sysconfig.get_paths()
```

which will return us a `dict` with all the relevant variable names as keys, and corresponding paths as values.
When we know the key we can get the value dynamically,

```py
>>> sysconfig.get_path("include")
'C:\\Program Files\\Python310\\Include'
```

However, the most convenient feature of `sysutils` for this situation is that it can list all the variables at once from the command-prompt by invoking `python -m sysconfig`:

```bash
$ python -m sysconfig

Platform: "macosx-10.4-i386"
Python version: "3.2"
Current installation scheme: "posix_prefix"

Paths:
        data = "/usr/local"
        include = "/Users/tarek/Dev/svn.python.org/py3k/Include"
        platinclude = "."
        platlib = "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/site-packages"
        platstdlib = "/usr/local/lib/python3.2"
        purelib = "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/site-packages"
        scripts = "/usr/local/bin"
        stdlib = "/usr/local/lib/python3.2"

Variables:
        AC_APPLE_UNIVERSAL_BUILD = "0"
        AIX_GENUINE_CPLUSPLUS = "0"
        AR = "ar"
        ARFLAGS = "rc"
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe below command line works for you if all of above methods didn't work.

`sudo apt-get install cython cython3`