# Cmake shows "PYTHON_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND" in Windows

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

Cmake shows "PYTHON_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND" in Windows

I have been trying to implement https://github.com/yuanming-hu/spgrid_topo_opt/tree/master/topo_opt. I am not able to do it in few weeks. When I try to build the project and configure it. It gives me some errors.

It says "ERROR: Invalid pattern is specified in "path:pattern" and also "PYTHON_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND". I tried for looking for solutions, but those are for Linux and I am using windows.

Comment: "I tried for looking for solutions, but those are for Linux and I am using windows." What have you tried? Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33759845/4720025) answer and the link therein? If it's Python 3.x, maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17872234/how-to-add-python-to-windows-registry) question helps. Could you not provide a [mcve]? We do not see which version of Python, CMake and other utilities you are using.

Comment: python 3.7 (64 bit) . Cmake 3.14.4. Visual studio 2017

Comment: @ArdaAytekin I looked to the answers and those were for linux and couldn't get much help from it

Comment: I doubt you have checked the links I shared with you in my previous comment --- they are explicitly for Windows. I am unaware of any registry-related tasks on Linux systems. Anyways... Good luck, then.

Comment: @ArdaAytekin Thanks. I checked the path (the solution it was given) and it's there in the registry. Could be there any other kind of faults?