# How do I resolve this make fatal error: numpy/arrayobject.h: No such file or directory?

Tags: python, c, numpy, makefile, gnu-make

I have the following snippet in my `makefile` (the first line was added by me after finding it as a candidate solution online - unfortunately, it doesn't work):

```
$(shell set(PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS} /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/core/include))

all: obj $(EXEC) link
$(EXEC): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(COMMON) -I./src/factor $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)
    $(CC) -shared $(COMMON) -I./src/factor $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $(SHAREDLIB) $(LDFLAGS)
$(OBJDIR)%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) $(COMMON) -I./src/factor $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

I verified that `numpy/arrayobject.h` is in `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/core/include` on my system. After executing `make` I get:

```
gcc -I ./include -I/usr/include/python3.5 -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda-10.0/include/ -DCUDNN  -I./src/factor -Wall -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -DGPU -DCUDNN -c ./src/ComputationPy.c -o obj/ComputationPy.o
./src/ComputationPy.c:12:31: fatal error: numpy/arrayobject.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:51: recipe for target 'obj/ComputationPy.o' failed
make: *** [obj/ComputationPy.o] Error 1
```

Line 51 corresponds to the last line of the snippet.

Comment: You solve this error by making sure there is such file or directory..

Comment: Or by changing the reference to where it actually is. This may not be a makefile error but an include error.

Comment: If your sure all of the syntax is correct, but still seeing this error, then take a look at this conversation about [Cmake is not able to find Python-libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24174394/cmake-is-not-able-to-find-python-libraries)

Comment: That `$(shell ...)` construct is not doing anything useful.  If you were expecting it to add `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/core/include` to a Make variable called `PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS`, then that's your problem.  Use `+=` instead.

Comment: Setting a shell variable has no effect if you don't use it.  You need a `-I` in your build including that directory

Comment: @stark Given the log snippet shown, I'm pretty sure `$(PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS)` appears somewhere in the value of COMMON.

Comment: @zwol Adding COMMON += -I /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/core/include resolved the issue. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the *complete* Makefile it's hard to be sure what's wrong, but this line looks like it can't possibly be correct:

```
$(shell set(PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS} /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/core/include))
```

In GNU make, `$(shell ...)` runs `sh -c "..."` [technically, `$(SHELL) -c "..."`) and evaluates to whatever that command prints on its stdout.  `set(...)` is not valid sh syntax, and also, the stuff *inside* `$(shell ...)` cannot change Make variables.  I would expect this line to print an error message as part of the make log, something like

```
sh: 1: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
```

and otherwise have no effect.

Assuming the goal here is to append `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/core/include` to the value of the Make variable `PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS`, the way to do that is with `+=`:

```
PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS += /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/core/include
```

The rules you quoted don't *directly* make use of this variable, but I suspect there may be a reference to it hiding inside `$(COMMON)`.