# Pyenv-installed Python creates virtualenv with empty include dir, no python-config in bin

Tags: virtualenv, include-path, pyenv, pyenv-virtualenv

Note: There are several similar questions, which I have seen and read. None of them are the precise problem I'm having, and none of their answers work for me.

I have installed several Python versions (Python 2.7, 3.8, 3.9, and 3.10) on my macOS Ventura system using [Pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv). The installed directories include a `python-config` file in `/bin` and an `/include` directory with many header files, so I do not need to install python-devel or similar:

```
$ ls -al /Users/williamsn/.pyenv/versions/3.10.9/bin/*-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 williamsn  staff    17 Dec 19 17:24 
/Users/williamsn/.pyenv/versions/3.10.9/bin/python-config -> python3.10-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 williamsn  staff    17 Dec 19 17:24 
/Users/williamsn/.pyenv/versions/3.10.9/bin/python3-config -> python3.10-config
-rwxr-xr-x  1 williamsn  staff  2073 Dec 19 17:24 
/Users/williamsn/.pyenv/versions/3.10.9/bin/python3.10-config
$ ls -al /Users/williamsn/.pyenv/versions/3.10.9/include/python3.10/
total 1192
drwxr-xr-x  86 williamsn  staff   2752 Dec 19 17:24 .
drwxr-xr-x   3 williamsn  staff     96 Dec 19 17:24 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 williamsn  staff   3224 Dec 19 17:24 Python.h
...
-rw-r--r--   1 williamsn  staff   3026 Dec 19 17:24 import.h
...
-rw-r--r--   1 williamsn  staff  48878 Dec 19 17:24 pyconfig.h
...
-rw-r--r--   1 williamsn  staff   2863 Dec 19 17:24 weakrefobject.h
```

As a best practice, I work exclusively in virtualenvs to keep the base Python installation clean and pristine. I create my virtualenvs using the [`venv`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html) module built in to Python 3:

```
$ python3.10 -m venv my_venv
```

After doing so, there are two problems:

1. The `my_venv/include` directory is empty (does not contain the `python3.10` directory or any of the header files from the parent Python and does not symlink to the parent Python)
2. There is no `python-config` / `python3-config` / `python3.10-config` in `my_venv/bin`.

So, for things requiring the Python headers:

- If it tries to find the headers using `python-config` (which many projects do), it will fail.
- If it tries to find the headers using the Python prefix and adding `/include` to it (which many projects do, notably Boost), it will fail.
- If it tries to find the headers by importing `sysconfig` and calling `sysconfig.get_paths()`, it will succeed, albeit with paths outside the virtualenv.

Now, on a case-by-case basis, I can work around this, and already have. I can manually copy over `python_config` and then either `export CPATH` to add `/Users/williamsn/.pyenv/versions/3.10.9/include/python3.10` or modify the virtualenv to symlink to `/Users/williamsn/.pyenv/versions/3.10.9/include`. These work, but they don't seem right to me. I can't make a global workaround anywhere (such as exporting `CPATH` in my Bash profile), because I'm working with multiple Python versions, and I'd end up with the wrong headers half the time. It seems to me like a virtualenv that has an empty `include` directory and is missing `python-config` when its parent has a full `include` directory and contains `python-config` is a broken virtualenv.

Is there an option I'm missing to include these pieces? Is this a bug I need to file against Python/`venv`?

Comment: Have you found any solutions to this problem since? I’m running into this as well. Thanks!

Comment: I have not. We settled with committing a workaround to our devenv scripts to copy `python-config` and then symlink the include dir. And this problem is not limited to macOS (we have had to implement the workaround for other platforms, too), but it's not a problem on all platforms.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid there is, and has ever been, no straightforward and universal measures for this issue so far (n.b., the current most-recent stable version is Python-3.12.2 at the time of writing).  Considering that the issue was once long-standing since 2011 and closed in 2019 with no applicable solutions ([Issue #169: python-config should be linked](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/169)), the chance for the core developers of Python/`venv` to provide the functionality for it in the future seems slim to me, unfortunately.

### Background

Here is my guess of why it is not supported by `venv`.  In short, there is no *definitive* and solid way.

There is usually no direct or reliable way from a (statically compiled) Python (binary) command to find the corresponding *include* or (C-type) *library* paths.  Instead, Python provides the utility command `python-config`, which basically works on the assumption that the first `python-config` in your command-line search path corresponds to the Python command of your interest.  This assumption may be unreliable in general, and this is particularly the case if you combine `venv` with `pyenv`.

In the `pyenv` environment, `python-config` is fixed at `~/.pyenv/shims/python-config` (providing you have installed `pyenv` in your home directory).  The script `python-config` of `pyenv`, which is a small-size wrapper script common to all Python versions, works fine as long as you stay in the pure `pyenv` environment.  However, it does not work as expected as soon as you get out of it with `venv`.  Examine the following situation, for example.

```bash
% cd ~
% pyenv shell 3.12.2
% python -m venv .venv3_12
% pyenv shell 3.9.0
% python --version  # => 3.9.0
%
% source ~/.venv3_12/.venv3_12/bin/activate
(.venv3_12) % python --version     # => 3.12.2
(.venv3_12) % which python-config  # => ~/.pyenv/shims/python-config
(.venv3_12) % python-config --prefix
   # => ~/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0  (!!)
```

As you see in the last line, the return value of `python-config` does **not** correspond to the *currently venv-activated* Python.
This is because *venv* does not create its own `python-config` in its path (which should come at the head of the command-line search path), so the first `python-config` in your command-line search path is the one managed with `pyenv`; and as far as `pyenv` is concerned, the currently-activated version of Python is 3.9.0, as opposed to *venv*-managing 3.12.2.

To add, I am afraid there is no universally-applicable way for Python-`venv` to know how to create `python-config`.  Remember `pyenv`-controlled `python-config` is, on its face value, just a very short shell script, and so simply copying it under a `venv`-controlled directory does not work.  Of course, the Python core-developer team (including the `venv` maintainers) does not need to or perhaps does not care about `pyenv`, which is a mere third-party tool.

As such, I am afraid it is tricky for `venv` to provide an equivalent command to `python-config`.

### Potential measures

Therefore, the remedy for this issue should be (at least for now) case-by-case basis.
One of the OP's way of setting the environmental variable(s) `CPATH` or else appropriately is another.  Or, depending on the `configure` script, you may symlink the correct include and lib files or directoies to/under `/Your/Venv/Dir/{include,lib}` .
Or, a past answer on Stackoverflow "[Why `pyvenv` does not install `python-config`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42020937/3577922)" provides one solution (I have not tested it personally).

Or, an alternatively way is to employ the [*conda*](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/index.html) framework to replace `pyenv` and `venv` altogether. In the *conda* framework, you can access the right `python-config` in your currently-activated Python environment.  If you frequently need to compile user-modules of Python, this may be an easier solution.