# invalid syntax in Python function

Tags: python, function, syntax

```
[joepareti54@xxx build]$ ./manta ../scenes/_trainingData.py --dim 3 --addModelGeometry True --addSphereGeometry True
Version: mantaflow 64bit fp1 commit dd3bb0c0a65cc531d3c33487bde5edcb4aa6784f from Mar 14 2018, 14:53:44
Loading script '../scenes/_trainingData.py'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../scenes/_trainingData.py", line 12, in <module>
    from Emitter import *
  File "/home/joepareti54/FluidNet/manta/scenes/Emitter.py", line 15, in <module>
    import matlabnoise
  File "/home/joepareti54/FluidNet/manta/build/../../../matlabnoise/matlabnoise.py", line 81
    def Perlin2D(*args) -> "double" :
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I believe the invalid syntax occurs in:

```
def Perlin2D(*args) -> "double" :`enter code here`
  return _matlabnoise.Perlin2D(*args)
Perlin2D = _matlabnoise.Perlin2D
```

Comment: You're running the script in a Python version incompatible with what the script requires.

Comment: thanks folks, and thanks for formatting my post ... I am not really sure: [joepareti54@xxx build]$ which python
/anaconda/envs/py35/bin/python
[joepareti54@xxx build]$ however renaming the above definition is inconsequential, i.e. the ./manta command returns exactly the same error

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `mantaflow` is running an embedded Python, so the version used is the one that was available when `mantaflow` was compiled and it appears that version does not support the type annotations introduced in Python 3.5

When you run `which python` that shows you the version of Python installed on your system, not the version compiled into the other program.

Solutions include recompiling mantaflow with a more recent Python, or stop using type annotations.

Comment: thank you: because the first step to build manta involves using cmake, I found the following hints to specify another version of python -- not tried it out yet just to avoid screwing up --- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15291500/i-have-2-versions-of-python-installed-but-cmake-is-using-older-version-how-do

Comment: can anybody propose a python 2 - compatible re-write of the function "def Perlin2D" listed above --- Thx

Comment: @josephpareti, just remove the `-> "double"` and it should run on Python2