# making cmake link to the right Python library by setting DPYTHON_LIBRARY varible

Tags: python, cmake

I'm trying to change my python path in make but I'm not able to.

When I run the command it's asking me for the input

Vsvss-MacBook-Pro:Tello_Video vsvsvarma$ cmake -DPYTHON_LIBRARY=/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/libpython2.7.dylib"
>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting Python library is not enough. You should also set `PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR` and `PYTHON_EXECUTABLE`

Follow this link:
[I have 2 versions of python installed, but cmake is using older version. How do I force cmake to use the newer version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15291500/i-have-2-versions-of-python-installed-but-cmake-is-using-older-version-how-do)