# Running CMAKE couldn't find python executable

Tags: python, cmake, exe

Link for the issue raised in github: [github issue link for reference](https://github.com/Ultimaker/Cura/issues/8445)

Application Version: CURA 3.6 version

Platform:

- Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8300H CPU @ 2.30 GHz
- RAM: 16.0 GB
- System type: 64-bit Operating system, x64-based processor

### Steps to Reproduce

I am trying to run source from https://github.com/Ultimaker/Cura/wiki/Running-Cura-from-Source-on-Windows#microsoft-visual-studio-2019.
And attempting to run step 10.
10:

> Open CMake and point its source directory to your cura-build repository and the build directory to the build subdirectory.

### Actual Results

```
D:\work\cura-build-master\cura-build-master\build>cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=../install_dir -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -G "NMake Makefiles" ..
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.0.24215.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.0.24215.1
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: D:/MicrosoftVisualStudio14.0/VC/bin/amd64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: D:/MicrosoftVisualStudio14.0/VC/bin/amd64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:165 (message):
Could NOT find Python3 (missing: Python3_EXECUTABLE Interpreter)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:458 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindPython/Support.cmake:2966 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindPython3.cmake:389 (include)
CMakeLists.txt:94 (find_package)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "D:/work/cura-build-master/cura-build-master/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

### Expected results

CMake should generate all files in build directory.

From the above error it is evident that the CMake is not able to find `python` executable.

I have no python installed on system. The only python available is from the CURA (which is installed when the `cura-build-environment` is build). How to link or make the CMake find the python executable which is installed?

For my case it is installed/found the executable in this folder:
`\cura-build-environment-master\install_dir\bin`

Comment: There are many questions on Stack Overflow about hinting CMake about python executable. Have you checked them? Have you tried what is suggested in answers to [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15291500/i-have-2-versions-of-python-installed-but-cmake-is-using-older-version-how-do)? (E.g. [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15291663/3440745) suggests to pass `-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=/path/to/python` parameter to `cmake`).

Answer (score 0):

I have checked and found that we can set the python executable:

for windows:
set(Python3_EXECUTABLE D:/cura-build-environment-master/install_dir/bin/python.exe)